# How to perform audio level metering with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, metering

My app streams remote audio content using MPMoviePlayerController.  I would like to do VU metering (audio level metering) as done in the avTouch sample code from apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html), but MPMoviePlayerController does not have such methods for metering.

Is there any way to implement a VU meter for streaming audio?